# Prestashop. Turning off auto modules update in Adminitration -> Settings doesnt work

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Ive stuck with the problem, that every module sometimes have to be updated. I turned off automatic search for updates (at admin's page), but still no success, updates are coming and this becomes a real pain in my a**, because iam fixing some of them by changing controllers and other php files, and when updates are implemented - all php files are overwritten by new one. Also, when module is need to be updated - its just stop working and becomes non-configurable, so as for me its very painful procedure to update modules. Can U guys give me some clues? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the way you are making your changes. Anyways, Overriding is a good practice in developping/adding/changing  with Prestashop and any other MVC based programming. When you upgrade, the overrides stay in place and keep the functionality.

I have never tried to override the behaviour of a module but I am pretty sure there is a way to do so since everything is written in the MVC way. Then, the module updates will only concern the core files of the module and your changes will stay in the override place.

One thing to watch about  overrides is that when you upgrade major versions the override might not be compatible with the changes made to the new controllers. But still here, if your overrides should upgrade, it will be done separately.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Sad, but i've rad that module's .php files CANNOT be overrided in /override/ folder or any other way =( It would be great if someone knows the correct way to override those files.

Comment: I suggest you open another post where you give a specific case. Generally, Stackoverflow community pay attention to questions that are specific and contain details/code. Choose a module and give an example of added code and how it was broken after module upgrade. Good luck

Comment: But first, tell us here please, where did you read that PHP files of module CANNOT be overriden?

Comment: Look here.. they said, that php files couldnt be overrided

http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/273451-how-to-override-the-class-of-modulesblockreinsuranceblockreinsurancephp/

Comment: I agree that most topics on official website say the same thing but, Did you tried somthing like this: http://www.circonflex.fr/actus/overrider-fichiers-php-module-prestashop-29/ ??? I am just trying to help, even with things I didn't test.